# join multiple files of database using java (android) results in corrupted database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, split

I'm trying to join several files of a database in android. The file was split in the first place because of the limitation in 1MB of size of any files within the apk for android versions prior to 2.3. The file I'm trying to join together is a database, which is complicated in its own way to be placed in the right folder for SQLite to read it, and I'm using the following method:

```
private void copyDB() throws IOException {
        // list the files the db is splitted into
        int[] cc = { R.raw.cc1, R.raw.cc2, R.raw.cc3 };
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH+DB_NAME);

        for (int k : cc) {
            InputStream in = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(k);
            int count;
            byte[] filebytes = new byte[1024];
            while((count = in.read(filebytes)) != -1) 
                out.write(filebytes, 0, count);
            in.close();
        }

        // clean up
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
```

As you can see, I'm using plain streams to join the files back together, and I'm almost positive that it works because it performs as expected with android 2.3. However, when I test on android 2.2 I'm getting a corrupt database (I don't have with me the exact message from the LogCat but the SQL error was 'Error: database disk image is malformed')

Is there anything that I can do to prevent the database from corrupting when I place it in the /data/data/package.name/database/ folder?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have come across the same problem ... have you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is not strictly the answer to your question, but may resolve your problem. When I encountered this problem, I believe I renamed the file to force Android to treat it as an uncompressable binary (gave it an extension of .mp3).

Comment: I did so and, effectively, the file was not compressed anymore (the size was very different). However, I got the same error about the corrupt database after moving the file to the database folder. Maybe android writes some kind of metadata on the file hence the corruption detected by sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, however I realized that it was the way I was splitting my db incorrectly. Originally I split it this way;

split largeFile.db -b 1M largeFile

i was forgetting the .db at the end of the second largeFile hence,

split largeFile.db -b 1M largeFile.db

solved my problem. I then moved all my largeFile.dbaa, largeFile.dbab, ... in the assets (I suppose raw your case works as well) folder and renamed them to largeFileA, largeFileB,...

Maybe this helps